# Language version selector for a topic in Documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Currently we can select multiple language versions for a topic in Documentation, for example, [`Exception Filters`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/46/exception-filters#t=201702210529109003647) is a new feature since C# 6, the corresponding language version is `6.0` and `7.0`(instead of `>=6.0`)

What happens to these documents when C# 8.0 is released? Do we need to edit all the documents then? Is it better to use a "range selector" since break changes of language features between versions are rare?

Answer (score 1):

Languages usually don't make breaking changes on topic-level features. And usually when they do, it's a big deal and people tend to know about it before it happens.

So I would say that, by default, you should use ranges for topic-level versions. Only use specific versions if you have a reason to believe that it won't apply in the future.

Comment: Agree, but now we can't use ranges for versions, we can only select multiple versions on the web page.

Comment: Or rather, we can currently do "all versions" or "specific subset of *current* versions."